# How to programmatically set the user timezone

Tags: 8, users, datetime

I am programmatically creating a user and wanted to assign a timezone for the user

I am able to successfully create a user by the following code

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::create();
$user->setPassword('1233455');
$user->enforceIsNew();
$user->setEmail($item['Home - Email']);
$user->setUsername($item['First Name']);
```

How do I assign the timezone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3Aset/8.4.x) method on `user` Entity like the following:

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::create();
$user->setPassword('1233455');
$user->enforceIsNew();
$user->setEmail($item['Home - Email']);
$user->setUsername($item['First Name']);
//- Set Time Zone to London 
$user->set('timezone','Europe/London');
$user->save();
```

**NOTE :** You can set other fields with `set` method, for example if you can activate the user with `$user->set('status',1);` or give him administrator role with `$user->set('roles',['administrator']);` .